# Arrow-Kt Fx vs Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, arrow-kt

I am trying to learn `Arrow-Kt` since I got curious about `Functional Programming in Kotlin`.

Can someone explain why there is a need to create another construct that functions almost similarly to `Kotlin Coroutines`? or am I wrong in my understanding of this?

How do these two tie in together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## NEW ANSWER

This answer was already quite old, and was terribly outdated. Therefore I wanted to update this question, to reflect the current situation. At time of updating Arrow is version `1.1.2`, but this will most likely not change anymore in the future.

Arrow Fx **used** to implement its own runtime, but this caused a lot of friction with the existing eco-system that was build around KotlinX Coroutines. So instead of continuing our work on a custom runtime, we re-implemented all of Arrow Fx's APIs on top of KotlinX Coroutines with all the existing guarantees, and test suites passing. Effectively proofing that KotlinX Coroutines can support a functional effect system like we defined in Arrow Fx Coroutines.

So now Arrow Fx builds entirely on-top of KotlinX Coroutines, and thus adheres to all of its principles such as Structured Concurrency.

It does not longer have an `IO` type, but instead Arrow has changed it direction to fully support and embrace `suspend () -> A` (and `suspend CoroutineScope.() -> A` as we felt it was superior in both performance, and syntax.

Since then Arrow has invested most of its efforts in building monadic DSLs that work nicely together with `suspend`, such that you can more easily create complex workflows and *mix* concerns of `Either`, `suspend`, etc without requiring complex abstractions, or difficult theory. For example:

```kotlin
object MyError
object User

suspend fun fetchUser(): Either<MyError, User> =
    User.right()

suspend fun example(): Either<MyError, List<User>> = either {
  delay(10_000) // suspending sleep
  (0..10).parTraverse(Dispatchers.IO) { // parallel map on IO
    user().bind() // get `User` out of Either<E, User>
  }
}
```

As you can see above we can easily combine the powers of parallelism, concurrency and monadic operations in a Kotlin idiomatic manner.

So Arrow Fx and Kotlin/KotlinX Coroutines are now seemingly working together, and you can mix-and-match code however suits your needs.

Arrow Fx aims to offer some higher level operators in addition to KotlinX Coroutines, and other Arrow libraries such as Arrow Core aim to complement the language and eco-system in the same manner.

## OLD POST

> Arrow fx uses coroutines when dealing with IO, doesn't replace them. Similar to how Room has extensions that allow to use Flow.

That's incorrect, Arrow Fx builds a purely functional runtime library for Kotlin's suspend system. Just like KotlinX Coroutines builds runtime library for Kotlin's library.

So both libraries offer an implementation for Kotlin's suspend system and can be used interchange-ably or independently depending on your needs or use-cases.

Arrow Fx offers a purely functional lazy runtime for Kotlin’s suspend system with side-effect tracking and monad comprehensions (as shown by Pablisco).

It contains an `IO` type, which is equivalent to `suspend () -> A` and has many powerful concurrency primitives like `Semaphore`, `Queue`, `Ref`, `Promise`, etc.
They all guarantee resource safety, while offering powerful concurrent and parallel combinators and automatically cancellation support.
(In the next version we'll also have support for suspend () -> Either<E, A>)

In contrast to KotlinX Coroutines, which offers an eager implementation of Kotlin’s suspend system with cooperative cancellation support and a cold stream implementation.

Comment: Does this mean that I wont need to work with coroutines why Im using arrow? How about coroutine flow? Can I integrate coroutine flow with arrow? Or is there also an equivalent within arrow?

Comment: "Arrow Fx builds a purely functional runtime library for Kotlin's suspend system".. If i understood it correctly, arrow uses suspend functions but doesnt use coroutines (launch, deffered, etc) to run these suspend function?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones you're correct, Arrow does not use KotlinX Coroutines but it only uses the functions in the standard library. So it does not use launch, deferred, CoroutineScope, nor does it have those functions available on the classpath.

So you also don't have to work with coroutines when using Arrow Fx, and could use to only use Arrow Fx.  Arrow currently doesn't offer an alternative to `Flow` but this will actively be worked on next.

Comment: I see. Now my question is how does all of this fit with kotlin multiplatform? Does it work out of the box?

Comment: Also, since arrow doesnt offer Flow or something similar to it at the moment.. Is there still a way to tie in Flow with Arrow. Ive read about integration with RxJava in the docs, does this indicate to use RxJava instead?

Comment: With the next release of Arrow, there will also be an interop module for KotlinX structured concurrency.As of today you could already mix both in your project and use them interchangeable using their prespective effect and suspend constructors.

Comment: Awesome! Seems like I need alot of time to learn of these stuff! Thank you very much youre a big help! <3

Comment: Hi @nomisRev, after doing some more reading, I now understand how arrow works and how it ties in with RxJava through "ObservableK" etc. Isn't something similar could be done with Coroutines Flow? Just have something like a "FlowK"? is that what you mean by "With the next release of Arrow, there will also be an interop module for KotlinX structured concurrency"?

Comment: Hi Archie,
That is. definitely possible! We have a KotlinX module available already but currently it only adds some methods for interoperating with structured concurrency.

But we could definitely add support for `Flow` like we have for RxJava and Reactor as well. If you're interested in working or helping in that area I'd be happy to give more help on Slack in more detail :) This is on the roadmap for that module.

Comment: Awesome! I will study arrow more in the coming days hope I'll come to a point that I could help! :D

Answer (score 2):

Arrow fx uses coroutines when dealing with `IO`, doesn't replace them. Similar to how Room has extensions that allow using `Flow`.

However, fx can be used with single threaded components like Option or Either.

```
val ab :Option<Int> = Option.fx {
  val a: Int = maybeA.bind()
  val b: Int = maybeB.bind()
  a + b
}
```

As you can see if any of the maybes is Absent then the result will be absent. This is equivalent to doing:

```
maybeA.flatMap { a -> 
  maybeB.map { b -> a + b }
}
```

Which can get messy when dealing with loads of these functional data types.

So, Arrow fx helps how we work with bindings in a way that makes it more functional.

Furthermore, we now have Arrow Meta (WIP) which uses compiler plugins to make Arrow even more seamless. In the future we will be able to do something like this:

```
val ab :Option<Int> = Option.fx {
 val a: Int by maybeA
 val b: Int by maybeB
 a + b
}
```